# Change only the number inside var?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you have:

```
   var something = $('.element').text();
    // something = 'The tortoise ran 5 times faster than the fox.';
```

Is there a way I can edit it to change the "5" to a different number in a new var? So I get

```
newSomething = 'The tortoise ran 6 times faster than the fox.';
```

NOTE: the number from var something is dynamic and be anything from 0 -> 100's, I need to increment it by one and I need to increment it on the fly (I cannot assign the number to a var as it is coming from document load and is being assigned )

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you tell us, we may be able to provide more details or come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var something = $('.element').text();
var newSomething = something.replace(/\d+/, function(match) {
    return (Number(match) + 1).toString();
});
```

Some info on what's happening: the code uses a more complex form of the [`str.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function. The normal form just takes two strings, and replaces any occurrence of the first string with the second string.

`str.replace` can also take a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to search for (in this case, `\d+`, which means "one or more digits"), along with a replacer function, as I've used here. I've used an anonymous function expression, which takes a single argument `match`. This function is called for every single match, so if your string has multiple matches, it'll be run multiple times.

In the function, the match (which is a string) is being converted to a number, incremented, and then converted back to a string. This is then returned as the result of the match replacer.

Comment: Or did you want something more useful?

Comment: This is clearly the correct answer and sufficient for OP's question.

Comment: That is good and the correct answer, but what if the number is dynamic? I might need to change X number on the fly, but I cannot set it as 'the tortoise ran ' + num +'... as someone else suggested as it comes from php

Comment: @user2413333: Is it always a number? Do you know which number? Is there only going to be one number? Do you need to increment it? Why doesn’t PHP just give you “5”?

Comment: It will always be a number, but I do not know which number, it can be anyhing from 1-100's. I need to increment it by one

Comment: user2413333: You need to provide more context. We can't read your mind.

Comment: Yes, I know, sorry I didn't think it 100% through!

Comment: @user2413333: The fact that you're using PHP is probably important. Is the number available in JavaScript already, or do you need to push it from the server side?

Comment: So I can think of a solution using Javascript, and you *could* just paste it in if I were to post it as an answer, but understanding it may be out of your depth, and if you're learning, understanding is important. Can you try to give some more explanation of the situation to say why you apparently think this is the absolute only way to solve what you need? I think the solution would be simpler then.

Comment: Php creates the sentence, and I am assigning to a var using .text();. I realize my original question was missing a lot of key information! Sorry!

Comment: I understand that PHP generates the sentence; are you in any way in control of the PHP code itself, or is that outside of your control? One random suggestion; if this is displayed in some HTML element, you could wrap the number within the text in tags like so: `<span id="thenumber">1</span>`. Then, it will be much easier to change it in Javascript.

Comment: You still haven't made it clear about the PHP details. Either way, try moving your script block to the footer (after the PHP block.)

Comment: Yes! I will try the span thing! thank you very much for all your help :)

Answer (score 1):

define a var ...

```
var num = 5;
var something = 'The tortoise ran ' + num + ' times faster than the fox.';

function whatever(){
 num++;
something = 'The tortoise ran ' + num + ' times faster than the fox.';
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand the downvotes for this answer. I upvoted it because it conveys a method of solving the problem by updating the variable instead of using built-in functions to replace the same. It is quite a valid aproach I feel.

Answer (score 1):

How about in php wrapping a span around your number so you can access it easily with javascript:

**HTML**

```
<span class="element">The tortoise ran <span class="number">6</span> times faster than the fox.</span>
```

Then with javascript you can access the number easily:

**Javascript**

```
var number = Number($('.number').text());
$('.number').text(number + 1);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/42AzK/2/)**